XGBoost Early Stopping Rounds
my code below keeps blowing up and I can't work out what is going on
import optuna
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Assuming `X` and `y` are your feature matrix and target array
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(df_combined, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Define the objective function for Optuna
def objective(trial):
    # Suggest values for hyperparameters
    params = {
        "objective": "reg:squarederror",
        "eval_metric": "rmse",
        "tree_method": "hist",  # Use hist method
        "device": "cuda",       # Specify using GPU
        "learning_rate": trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 0.01, 0.3, log=True),
        "max_depth": trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 3, 10),
        "min_child_weight": trial.suggest_float("min_child_weight", 1, 10),
        "gamma": trial.suggest_float("gamma", 0, 1),
        "subsample": trial.suggest_float("subsample", 0.5, 1.0),
        "colsample_bytree": trial.suggest_float("colsample_bytree", 0.5, 1.0),
        "lambda": trial.suggest_float("lambda", 1e-3, 10.0, log=True),
        "alpha": trial.suggest_float("alpha", 1e-3, 10.0, log=True),
        "n_estimators": 1000  # Define n_estimators in the initialization of the model
    }

    # Initialize the model
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(**params)

    # Train the model with early stopping callback
    model.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
        verbose=False,
        early_stopping_rounds=50  # Stops if no improvement after 50 rounds
    )

    # Predict and calculate RMSE for validation set
    preds = model.predict(X_valid)
    rmse = mean_squared_error(y_valid, preds, squared=False)

    return rmse  # Optuna minimizes this

# Set up the Optuna study
study = optuna.create_study(direction="minimize")

# Optimize the hyperparameters
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100, n_jobs=40)  # 100 trials with 40 parallel jobs

# Display the best trial
print("Best trial:")
trial = study.best_trial
print(f"  Value (RMSE): {trial.value}")
print("  Params: ")
for key, value in trial.params.items():
    print(f"    {key}: {value}")

I get
TypeError: XGBModel.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'early_stopping_rounds'

I have updated everything to ensure I have all updated libraries.
Early stopping rounds is correct (I think) but just blows up for some reason.

EarlyStoppingRounds was added to XGBoost in 1.4.0.
If the version is below 1.4.0, upgrade XGBoost with:
pip install --upgrade xgboost

xgboost/releases/tag/v1.4.0

I have already tried that. Thanks

I think you're using xgboost>=2.0. In this case, early_stopping_rounds should be in params:
def objective(trial):
    # Suggest values for hyperparameters
    params = {
        "objective": "reg:squarederror",
        "eval_metric": "rmse",
        "tree_method": "hist",  # Use hist method
        "device": "cuda",       # Specify using GPU
        "learning_rate": trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 0.01, 0.3, log=True),
        "max_depth": trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 3, 10),
        "min_child_weight": trial.suggest_float("min_child_weight", 1, 10),
        "gamma": trial.suggest_float("gamma", 0, 1),
        "subsample": trial.suggest_float("subsample", 0.5, 1.0),
        "colsample_bytree": trial.suggest_float("colsample_bytree", 0.5, 1.0),
        "lambda": trial.suggest_float("lambda", 1e-3, 10.0, log=True),
        "alpha": trial.suggest_float("alpha", 1e-3, 10.0, log=True),
        "n_estimators": 1000,  # Define n_estimators in the initialization of the model
        "early_stopping_rounds": 50,
    }

    # Initialize the model
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(**params)

    # Train the model with early stopping callback
    model.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
        verbose=False,
        # early_stopping_rounds=50  # Stops if no improvement after 50 rounds
    )

Ref: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/9986
